# How can I customize tab completion in Perl's Term::Shell?

Tags: perl, tab-completion

I am using [Term::Shell](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::Shell) package to implement a CLI tool. This package provides a API: `comp_CMD`.

This function is invoked whenever the user presses the TAB. 
My requirement here is:

`shell> stack`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

`over under`

`shell>stack over<kbd>TAB</kbd>

`flow sample junk`

But the default `comp_CMD` provides only one set of TAB options like

`shell> stack` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

`over under`

`shell>stack over<kbd>TAB</kbd>

`over under` ### THE PROBLEM IS HERE

Instead of ***over under***  here, I want to get ***flow sample junk***.

Comment: Well, now that I have looked at Term::Shell, I notice that you need to write `sub comp_stack`. Am I wrong? What is in your `comp_stack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `comp_*` style handlers one can only match one's completions against the last incomplete word. Fortunately, however, you can get the desired result by overriding the catch_comp function like below; it lets one match against whole command line:

```
my %completion_tree = (
    stack => { under => [],
               over  => [qw(flow sample junk)] }
);

sub catch_comp {
    my $o = shift;
    my ($cmd, $word, $line, $start) = @_;

    my $completed = substr $line, 0, $start;
    $completed =~ s/^\s*//;

    my $tree = \%completion_tree;
    foreach (split m'\s+', $completed) {
        last if ref($tree) ne 'HASH';
        $tree = $tree->{$_};
    }

    my @completions;
    $_ = ref($tree);
    @completions =      @$tree if /ARRAY/;
    @completions = keys %$tree if /HASH/;
    @completions =      ($tree)if /SCALAR/;

    return $o->completions($word, [@completions]);
}
```

Comment: thanks Inshalla... i am a newbie to Perl.. I have copied ur code in to mine.. Now the problem is i dunno what changes should i make in sample code and get the expected output.. Sorry, if i am asking for too much.. Can you just write the comp_CMD module for me?..

Comment: You can just copy/paste the function above as it is, without modifications. Only the $completion_tree needs to be modified. If the syntax gives you problems have a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html . It should actually be fairly obvious how to modify it, since the example above represents exactly the kind of completion you expect; just change "stack" to whatever your command is; "under" and "over" are your first parameters; "flow" etc. are second parameters, but only available if "over" is the first. You can grow the tree to arbitrary size.

Comment: I am able to use that now.. Thanks a lot Inshalla :) :)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing i want to add here..

After overriding rl_complete subroutine, we also have to override comp__ (Default subroutine called for TAB) to avoid repeated printing of the subcommands.